# How can I farm credits quickly?

Tags: warframe

With the new Rising Tide update, I need 6 million credits to build my own railjack. What are the easiest/quickest ways to farm credits quickly?

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, if you want to farm credits quickly, you will want to have a [credit booster](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Credit_Booster), but it is not required. You can get a credit booster from the market, Baro Ki'teer, Rare/Reinforced storage containers, or Daily Tributes.

### Sell Duplicates

The first thing to do when looking for credits is to check how many duplicate blueprints and mods you have, as they can be sold for credits. There are a number of blueprints, such as Oberon parts, that drop very frequently, and each one can be sold for 3,500 credits, so sell your extras that you don't need. You can also sell mods for credits if you have extra duplicates and don't need endo.

### Dark Sectors

The least difficult way to farm credits is to do [Dark Sector](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Sectors) missions, as they reward 10,000-20,000 credits per completion which is doubled with a booster. You will only face infested enemies ranging in levels 6-40 based on the planet, making it relatively easy to solo. Popular nodes for this are Akkad/Eris, and Seimeni/Ceres where you can get 18,000 and 20,000 credits for completing 5 waves. This bonus will be doubled if you have a [Daily First Win Bonus](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Daily_Tribute) and combined with a credit booster, it is quadrupled.

### Sortie

Another method of farming credits is to do the daily sortie. You will receive 20,000 for the first mission, 30,000 for the second mission and 50,000 for the third. However, this can only be done once a day, and you will have to face enemies level 60-100 so it is not necessarily easy for newer players.

### Neptune Disruption

You can also farm credits doing Laomedeia, Neptune, a Disruption mission which rewards 20,000, 30,000, and 50,000 credits for Rotation A, B, and C respectively, and enemies start at levels 25-30

### Index

The most popular method of farming credits quickly is [the Index](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/The_Index). If you have a properly equipped team, you can farm credits very quickly, however the enemies are fairly high level, and have a lot of armor/shields depending on the difficulty you select. There are 3 difficulty levels for the Index

- Low: Investment- 30,000 Return- 105,000 Required Points- 50
- Medium: Investment- 40,000 Return- 175,000 Required Points- 75
- High: Investment- 50,000 Return- 250,000 Required Points- 100

Where enemy starting level increases with difficulty and scales with rounds.

To do the Index effectively, you will want to have the following team composition. (While not required, it speeds the process up and lowers chance of failing and losing credits. Highly recommended for high risk Index.)

- Goalie (Need at least 1): Limbo, Gara, Khora, Frost

  - Limbo is generally regarded as the best as he can be immune to damage in his void while having everything frozen that walks into his cataclysm. Also, offers a safe place for the DPS to hide.
- DPS (Recommended at least 1): Mesa, Banshee (Sonar), Nova (100-130% power strength), Excalibur Umbra
- Point Carrier (Need at least 1): Rhino, Revenant

  - Need to be tanky in ways other than Health/Shields as financial stress from picking up the points lowers your max health/shields and depletes your energy. Iron Skin and Mesmer Skin are the best ways to deal with this.
- Support (Recommended 1): Trinity (EV)

  - Picking up points depletes your energy, so having an EV Trinity to refill energy makes life easier for everyone. Also, EV Trinity has good single target damage.

Best weapons for the index are usually high damage status shoguns, such as Kohm, Tigris Prime, Hek. High damage crit based pistols are also useful, such as Pyrana (Prime), or various kitguns. Any high damage melee can also work.

To find a group for Index runs (most Pick up squads are chaotic), look in recruiting chat for people who are hosting Index runs, or host one your self. If you are posting a message in chat to try to find a group, use something like the following format.

> LF High Index. Can play Rhino/Limbo
>   H High Index. 2/4 Need Point carrier and dps

Comment: Trinity isn't the only viable support. Wisp is surprisingly effective at countering Financial Stress as long as she places her Reservoirs in good positions. I find it helps to have only the Vitality and Haste reservoirs up so you can set up 3 sets instead of 2.

Comment: Profit taker is good too

Answer (score 0):

## General Tips

- In general, you'll want a credit booster active while farming to maximize your credit gains. This won't apply to sold items, and only apply to mission rewards and credits dropped off of enemies. You can gain boosters without using platinum by:

  - Waiting for Baro Ki'Teer to offer a 3-day Credit Booster in his stock
  - Get lucky on a Daily Login Reward and receive a timed Credit Booster
  - Wait for a DE hosted 2x credit weekend for even more gains, as DE triggered events also stack with normal credit boosters.
- Use Warframes that can boost your credit gains. Every single bonus credit you get adds up, and these applies to Warframes and gear items that can boost your gains without too much investment. Things like:

  - Nekros / Nekros Prime's Desecrate
  - Chroma / Chroma Prime's Effigy
  - Secura Lecta's 2x credits on kill modifier
  - Smeeta Kavat's Charm bonus can yield double credits for a set amount of time

## The Index

Spamming low-risk investments is your best bet here. Avoid medium and high risk investments, as the seemingly high profit amounts are a trap -- the time spent to reach those levels is far longer than running the low risk investments over and over.  Advisable frame setups are a pure HP focused Inaros, Iron Skin focused Rhino, and weapons that have high one-shot kill capabilities and scale well up into high levels (ie Tigris/Prime, Catchmoon, etc).

There are a few more benefits to running low-risk investments over and over. In addition to having the highest credit to time ratios, due to the nature of enemy level scaling, you are also afflicted with no default financial stress modifier, and thus can survive longer without the need for hyper-specialized builds.

## Arbitrations

Arbitrations always give Credits 50,000 per completion. If you complete an Arbitration mission after you first login per day, this will be doubled to Credits 100,000.
Because the Sortie timer and the daily login timer are independent of each other (about 7 hours apart), you can exploit this to complete the first two Sortie missions, then complete the third Sortie after the daily login timer resets for an easy doubled first win bonus reward of Credits 100,000.

## Orb Vallis (Open World Venus)

Defeating the Profit-Taker Orb gives a base amount of Credits 125,000, but this may be less desirable for newcomers due to the requirements as well as difficulty of the fight to begin with.

## Dark Sectors

Hieracon on Pluto is one of the fastest ways to farm credits. Since it's an excavation mission, extracting after the first excavator has finished will yield Credits 20,000 in under 5 minutes. However, bear in mind that defending the extractor and keeping the power up may be hard for a lone player, so it's advised to bring someone along.

Sechura on Pluto, and Seimeni and Gabii on Ceres will give Credits 20,000 after the first 5 minutes/waves, extracting in the 5th minute/wave under few runs (3 or 4) will give high amounts of credits, Bear in mind the more people you have in your squad, the more credits you get (increasing by approximately Credits 1,000 per additional player).

[Source](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Credits)

Comment: Inaros isnt that great due to the max health reduction from financial stress

Comment: @Dragonrage If you are spamming low risk investments, which reward the most amount of credits earned per time ratio, then you will have a lot less Financial Stress at max points banked, compared to Medium and High risk investments

Comment: Given that it isnt efficient to only do 1 round of index, and 15 points held is the most efficient to turn in with, you will eventually have to deal with higher level enemies, and the financial stress debuff is still relevant

Comment: @Dragonrage Not sure what you're talking about. 3 turn ins at 15 yields 45, and at that point you only need 5 more kills to finish.Low Risk Index is far more efficient than Medium and high Risk, not only are you hitting a wall with level 100+ enemies as you attempt to finish up your points from 50-100, enemies are tougher and soak up more shots.

Comment: Just so we're clear, you do know that the profit from one round of Low Risk is 75,000 and the profit from one round of High Risk is 200,000?

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, and the time it takes to run Low Risk is signficantly lower than the time to run High Risk.   It has been debunked on Reddit countless times, it is far more efficient to run low index than to run High index.